# WooCommerce Add to Cart - Redirect to URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to just show a simple add to cart button at the bottom of a page. I can do so by using shortcodes:

`[add_to_cart id="99"]` or `[add_to_cart_url id="99"]`

The problem is that I want to then go to another URL that is not related to WooCommerce. It has to be customized depending on the page we are on.

An example would be:

1. Intro Landing page (add to cart at bottom)
    a. Action: adds product 99 to cart then redirects to #2.
2. Upsell page with 3 products on it
    a. Action: adds one of the three products to the cart and redirects to #3.
3. Second Upsell page with 1 product on it
    a. Action: adds the product to the cart and redirects to #4.
4. Checkout Page.

I was hoping there was a shortcode that I could use for Add to Cart and Redirect but can't find anything online. I have found a [custom redirect option that woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-a-custom-add-to-cart-url-to-redirect-to/) offers but it would set the redirect for all Add to Cart buttons.

I was thinking that there may be a way to create a function that expands the add to cart button shortcode so I can add a custom redirect URL to it.

For example: `[add_to_cart id="99" redirect="../step2/"]`

This can even be a URL that I can use in a link. I found that on [this page](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/) under the section titled "URL: Add One Simple Product to Cart & Redirect to Any Page Afterwards" that says I should be able to just use:

```
href="http://yourdomain.com/your_custom_page/?add-to-cart=25"
```

It adds the product to the cart but then just redirects to the cart (I have AJAX add to cart buttons enabled).

Any ideas may help!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this works: http://yourdomain.com/your_custom_page/?add-to-cart=25

I just had to uncheck the box in WooCommerce Settings that says to go to cart when someone clicks add to cart and make sure AJAX links was checked